# Error while creating external content type using SharePoint Designer 2013 against a SQL server 2012 Table

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, external-content-type, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create a `external content type` for my SharePoint 2013 environment using SharePoint designer 2013. The content type will be against a SQL Server 2012 table. The SQL instance is the same on which i have my SharePoint Config and Content databases. 
I am a farm admin. I am the database owner.

When i try to create a `SQL Server Connection` in SPD2013, by entering Database server name and Database name and using `Connect with User's Identity`. I get following error,

> Cannot connect to the LobSystem (External System). Reason: 'A
>   network-related or instance -specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)'

The SQL Server is configured to accept remote connections. On the SQL Server machine the `SQLServerConnection` is allowed in the Inbound Rules (of Firewall).

I am looking for any hints and directions, where i can move ahead.